# Name for the set of points x that can be written as the convex combination of $x_1\in S$ and $x_2 \in S$ such that $x_2 \geq x_1$

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have a set of points $S\subset\mathbb{R}_+^d$, which always includes the origin. I am interested in the set of all points $x$ that can be written as the convex combination of $x_1\in S$ and $x_2 \in S$, where $x_2 \geq x_1$ elementwise.

Is there a name for the set of all such points? Or is this set perhaps a union of well-understood objects? I'm studying objects of this type, and am looking for keywords to search in the literature.

The linked figure shows an example of constructing such a set from a set of points (black circles). The shaded region is the set of interest. [Example construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PShjB.png)

Comment: In a convex combination, who cares which component point is larger?

Comment: The requirement is that one element of the convex combination must strictly dominate the other. This is why, for example, the answer is not just the convex hull of S

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask a different question?

Comment: I see; I edited my question to indicate that $S$ is a set, not a single element of $\mathbb{R}_+^d$. Does this address the ambiguity?

Comment: Hmm, the set is not necessarily star shaped. In the plane take $S= \{0,e_1,e_2, e_1+2e_2 \}$, then the set in question is just the triangle joining the points, so it not even star shaped. It contains the star shaped set generated by $S$ but may have more points.

Comment: I thought you were right earlier, that the set must be star shaped (and that was very helpful). In the example you just described, the set would be the convex hull of the four points you specified, which is star-shaped around 0.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was sloppy, I meant that the set generated by the $S$ is my last comment was the set formed by joining all point of $S$ **except** the line between $e_1,e_2$. So it is not even star shaped.

Comment: I think you may have found another problem with my definition. For the $S$ you defined, I don't want my set to be just the three line segments $\{[0, e_1], [0, e_2], [0, e_1 + 2e_2\}$. My set should include any point $x$ that can be written as the convex combination of points in _those_ line segments, such that one point in the combination is strictly larger than the other. And this definition should be recursive, so we also include points that are the convex combination of _those_ points, with one strictly larger than the other.

Comment: I'm not sure how to define this set rigorously; I'll have to think more about this. In the picture I linked, the set I want is the entire purple set, not just the purple and red lines. I think, with this new recursive definition, this set should be star-shaped (and, in your example, it's the convex hull of $S$).